# AWS Glue job status using Java SDK

Tags: aws-glue

I have used below code to invoke Glue job from Lambda written in Java. How do I get the status of the job ?

```
    AWSGlue awsGlueClient = AWSGlueClient.builder().withRegion("us-east-1").build();
    StartJobRunRequest jobRunRequest = new StartJobRunRequest();
    jobRunRequest.setJobName("my_transformer");
    jobRunRequest.addArgumentsEntry("--Mode",mode);
    jobRunRequest.addArgumentsEntry("--Paramfile",paramfile);
    StartJobRunResult jobRunResult = 
    awsGlueClient.startJobRun(jobRunRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

The *startJobRun* function/action returns "JobRunId" which is a UTF-8 string and represents the ID assigned to current job run.

The *GetJobRun* function/action retrieves the metadata for a given job run. It takes the JobRunId as input and returns a JobRun object from which you can pull out current job status.

Reference AWS documentation :

[AWS Glue start job run](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-jobs-runs.html#aws-glue-api-jobs-runs-StartJobRun)

[AWS Glue get job run](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-jobs-runs.html#aws-glue-api-jobs-runs-GetJobRun)

[AWS Glue Job Run Object structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-jobs-runs.html#aws-glue-api-jobs-runs-JobRun)

Comment: Harsh,                                                                                                                            I added below lines. The state I am getting is null. Why is that so. I am expecting RUNNING.

        JobRun abc = new JobRun();
        abc.setId(jobRunResult.getJobRunId());
        String state = abc.getJobRunState();
        System.out.println(state);

Comment: Harsh, I am not getting option to call GetJobRub from awsGlueClient. I get getJobRun which takes GetJobRunRequest object. Can it be used to get the job state ?   Thx-Anirban

Comment: @Anirban : I have mainly used these APIs through python. There might be a few syntax changes and you will need to look into the java-sdk documentation for the correct syntax. The API is definitely getJobRun as per the above shared documentation. You will need to figure out the way to call it through Java-SDK.

Comment: You should look into creating a GetJobRunRequest object. Source code available here : https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-glue/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/glue/model/GetJobRunRequest.java

Answer (score 0):

We are building new Java V2 examples to work with AWS Glue. Once done, I will post a link to these new V2 examples. We will cover common use cases like how to create a crawler, how to start a crawler, and so on.

**UPDATE**
See the **GlueScenario.java** example that demonstrates how to perform multiple AWS Glue operations.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/glue/src/main/java/com/example/glue/GlueScenario.java